# what is the equivalent component of AWS Cognito in GCP for features like userpools, triggers and appclients?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-cognito, google-cloud-identity

We are migrating an application from AWS to GCP. In AWS, we use Cognito service for maintaining different types of users inside userpools (for example: SSO users has different userpool and users with email and password are configured in different userpool, for MFA users, they have different user pool) In AWS Cognito, we also leverage certain functionalities like appclient id and secret for generating JWT tokens and authorizer lambda in pre-sign up trigger)

How can we achieve the above implementation in GCP?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google [Identity platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/)  looks like amazon Cognito.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) as a equivalent of Amazon Cognito. This [table](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/mobile#languages_and_platforms) provides a comparison between Amazon Cognito and Firebase Authentication.